# nodejs httprequest with data - getting error getaddrinfo ENOENT

Tags: node.js, httprequest, getaddrinfo

### Update - Answered by self

I see one has to make sure that the DNS is resolved properly from the machine, check out [the node documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve_hostname_rrtype_callback) to make sure that domain is resolvable.

### Original Question

i am writing a nodes based program,in which the user can ask me to do a httprequest on their behalf {off course they provide me with some data, and method to call with} but every time i do a httprequest it gives me an error

getaddrinfo ENOENT
this is how my code looks

```
function makehttprequest(deviceid, httpaction, httppath,methods, actiondata, callback) {
console.log('we are here with httpaction' + httpaction + ' path ' + httppath + ' method ' + methods + ' action data ' + actiondata);
 //do the http post work, get the data, and call the callback function with return data
 var options = {
   host: httpaction,
   port: 80,
   path: httppath,
   method: methods
 };

    try {
      var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('error as : ' + e.message);
    }

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    // write data to request body
    console.log('writing data to request ..');
    req.write(actiondata);
    console.log('finished writing data to request…');
    req.end();
    console.log('request ended…');
}
```

Comment: For local development use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I've seen this happen when your host (which you pass in as httpaction) has the scheme (so "http://") in front of it. Your host should strictly be the domain like "www.google.com" not "http://www.google.com" or "www.google.com/hello-world" or "http://www.google.com/hello-world".

Keep it just the domain.

Here's an example: http://allampersandall.blogspot.com/2012/03/nodejs-http-request-example.html

Comment: +1 for "www.google.com" like host name instead of "http://www.google.com". This solved my problem.

Comment: You are an amazing guy! Wouldn't have figured this out.

Comment: If you need https you start the server slightly differently.

Comment: Worked like a charm :-). Superb catch.

Answer (score 8):

The problem can also happen if you have a trailing slash:

**Good:** `"www.google.com"`

**Bad:** `"www.google.com/"`

Answer (score 4):

Avoid all of these hostname/protocol/port/slash problems by using the `request` module instead of `http`

https://github.com/mikeal/request

Answer (score 3):

I was getting [Error: Getaddrinfo ENOENT], but it was right after getting [Error: connect EMFILE]; since I am doing load tests with thousands of clients the EMFILE error (the root cause) was being opaqued. The solution was [the same as for EMFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355501/connect-emfile-error-in-node-js): increase the number of file descriptors. Just adding it here for completeness in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this again today for a silly mistake. This was because port number was put as part of the hostname.

```
// wrong. gets error getaddrinfo ENOENT
var options = {
  hostName: 'localhost:1337',
  ....
}

// correct
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 1337,
};
```

Comment: If you're pulling the hostname from request headers (common for proxy), simply request.headers['host'].split(':')[0] to get rid of the port

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when calling `server.listen(PORT, HOST);` where HOST could not be resolved back to the local machine.

Once I changed this back to a hostname/domain name/ip that the local machine resolved to, this error went away.

Since I was trying to connect via a hostname for dev purposes I added an entry to my hosts file with the desired hostname and ensured that this matched the hostname passed to `server.listen()`

Answer (score 0):

If all your code seems to be alright and you're still get the same error, which was my case, the solution was checking the nameservers on my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

I added Google's nameserver at the beginning of my `resolv.conf` file (8.8.8.8) and the code started working just fine once again, no more error.

It's worth noticing that this error started happening on me on Feb. 4th 2015 after I ran an `sudo apt-get upgrade`, my node js must have been updated and a bug introduced which seemed to be incompatible with the nameservers I had.

At first I checked if I was having any DNS issues by fetching the URL I needed using `wget` on the command line, I got the contents of the target url fine so I didn't think it was actually a DNS issue, but it was.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but running as a AWS Lambda function, so in case someone is having this issue with Lambda functions this is how I got it resolved.

- Give your Lambda function a VPC.
- Select at least 2 Subnets.
- And select a Security Group.

I spent a day until I found this fix, hope it helps someone else.