# Problems making a node.js app connect to PostgreSQL, using node-orm (under osx 10.6.8)

Tags: macos, node.js, express

I am trying to make a small nodejs app run under osx (10.6.8), and connect to my localhost Postgres database. I am using node-orm (https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) as well as the Postgres bindings (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).

For some reason, when I use `orm.connect` and give it the connection url as a string, it fails with:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:123:16)
```

If I change localhost with 127.0.0.1. it also dies with a timeout exception.

Using the vanilla postgress bindings to connect to the DB, using the same connection string is successful, and I even managed to get a few test queries running, got results, etc.

I tried to set up the DB client manually using the vanilla postgress api, an pass it on to orm using `orm.use`. This manages to connect successfully to the DB, but every time I try to execute a query, nothing happens. It does not generate an error, but sinply gets stuck in the QueryQueue and doe not call the success callback. I checked the DB logs, and it seems that it has not detected the query either.

What do I do? I am a bit confused

Comment: This seems more like a DNS issue, rather than a node issue. Are you using http:// when specifying the connection to the DB? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580226/nodejs-httprequest-with-data-getting-error-getaddrinfo-enoent

Comment: This is my connection url: postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/db_name

Answer (score 8):

I came across this issue while on a plane. I only receive `Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT` when I'm not connected to a network, even though I'm running the database server locally. Here is what I did to fix it:

Instead of using `localhost`, use `127.0.0.1`.

So your connection string will change from

```
 postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/db_name
```

to

```
postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name
```

Comment: Faced the same problem while I was in the kitchen had unstable wifi. Changing to 127.0.0.1 fixed the problem for me! Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

Not able to make out real problem from the question.Looks like your connection string is wrong.
 But here is a code block which works with https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

`

```
var application_root = __dirname,
        pg = require('pg');

    // database

    var conString = "postgres://username:password@172.28.6.250:5432/db_name";

    function processReqResSql(req, res, sql) {
        pg.connect(conString, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404, {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                });
                res.write('{couldnt connect to db}');
            } else {


             var query = client.query(sql);
                /
                var dbResponse ="";
                query.on('row', function(row) {
                 console.log(row);

                  dbResponse = dbResponse+JSON.stringify(row);
                 });

                query.on('end', function() { 
                  client.end();
                   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                   res.write("{ results:{"+dbResponse+"}");

                   res.end();
             });

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your postgre server has started. 
You can start it by giving the following command:

```
pg_ctl -D <db-name> -l logfile start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add Headers as required ex. `Content-Type = application/json`

If this is not the error causing case you can replace your db config as:

**Old**:

```
var config = {
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'dbname',
        user: 'postgres',
        password: 'secret',
        port: 5432
    };
```

**Replaced Code:**

```
var config = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'dbname',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'secret',
    port: 5432
};
```

**And use this config to connect DB:**

```
const {
        Pool
    } = require('pg');
    const pool = new Pool(config);

    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
// Your code logic
};
```