# what is wrong with my simple node.js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Error:

```
/Users/user/node/app.js:3
makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid");
^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/node/app.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

app.js

```
var makeRequest = require('./make_request');

makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid");
makeRequest("Hello, this is dog");
```

make_request.js

```
var http = require('http');

var makeRequest = function(message) {

    //var message = "Here's looking at you, kid.";
    var options = {
        host: 'localhost', port:8080, path: '/', method: 'POST'
    }

    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    request.write(message);
    request.end();
};

exports = makeRequest;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return the `function` as the module object, set it to [`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports):

```
module.exports = makeRequest;
```

[`exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) is just a convenience copy of `module.exports`.

Comment: Better but still: `
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)`

Comment: Tried those but similar error: `events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:123:16)`

Comment: I don't really know. This is a `node.js` tutorial I am trying to do so I am very basic with it. It does look like some kind of error with the address though.

Comment: I found this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/kL7dZrUO89M So it is some connection issue but not sure how to diagnose or fix it.

Comment: Not working but that fixed that particular error so I will make a new question for the new error.

Comment: The code works fine for me if I change `exports =` to `module.exports =`.  It seems to me that there is a problem when DNS tries to resolve your hostname (which I am assuming is a website - not localhost).  Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580226/nodejs-httprequest-with-data-getting-error-getaddrinfo-enoent

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function.

```
makeRequest.makeRequest("Your message");
```

You can also simplify your code by doing:

```
module.exports.makeRequest = function(message) {
    //... 
};
```

Comment: Tried that but got this: `/Users/user/node/app.js:3 makeRequest.makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid"); ^ TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'makeRequest' at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/node/app.js:3:13) at Module._compile (module.js:449:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10) at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are importing a namespace on the first line of app.js. This namespace is make_request.
And you are also trying to call a function called makeRequest which is in the namespace make_request.
Just try this:

```
makeRequest.makeRequest("message"); on line 3 and 4 of app.js
```

Comment: Tried but got this: `/Users/user/node/app.js:3
makeRequest.makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid");
            ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'makeRequest'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/node/app.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
`

Comment: Yea maybe I should do some more tutorials before this super basic tutorial?