# Get response of url in nodejs (express/http)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I'm trying to get the response of two URLs in nodejs but there's a problem with http.request. Here's what I have so far:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/pretend/this/exists.xml";

var opt = {
    host: url.split(".com/")[0] + ".com",
    path: "/" + url.split(".com/")[1]
};
callback = function(response){
    var str = "";
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log(str);
    });
}
http.request(opt, callback).end();
```

and I'm getting this error

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

so I googled and got this stackoverflow issue 
[nodejs httprequest with data - getting error getaddrinfo ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580226/nodejs-httprequest-with-data-getting-error-getaddrinfo-enoent) in which the accepted answer says that you need to leave out the protocol.. but here's the issue, I need to check if

```
https://www.google.com/pretend/this/exists.xml
```

gives a 200 and if it doesn't (404) then I need to check if

```
http://www.google.com/pretend/this/exists.xml
```

gives a valid response

So that's the issue, I need to check a response by specific protocol.

Any ideas?

edit: 
Just now looking at the http doc (lazy I know) and I'm seeing http.get example.. I'll try that now

edit 2 :

so I tried this

```
http.get(url, function(res){
    console.log("response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e){
    console.log("error: " + e.message);
});
```

and apparently https is not supported.

```
Error: Protocol:https: not supported.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to listen to the `error` event on the request. If there is no handler attached, it will throw the error, but if there is one attached, it will pass the error as an argument in the asynchronous callback. In addition, you should use the `https` module for node, not `http` if you intend to make a secure request. So try this:

```
var https = require("https");

var url = "https://www.google.com/pretend/this/exists.xml";

var opt = {
    host: url.split(".com/")[0] + ".com",
    path: "/" + url.split(".com/")[1]
};

function callback(response) {
    var str = "";

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function () {
        console.log(str);
    });
}

var request = https.request(opt, callback);

request.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

request.end();
```

Comment: Yeah I just noticed the https library, I'm brand new to nodejs so I'll try that tomorrow thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you should require the http or https module, depending what you want use:

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
```

http/https modules is one of the cores of Node.js, so you don't need install with npm install.

And what is missing is listen to errors:

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com/pretend/this/exists.xml';

var options = {
   host: url.split('.com/')[0] + '.com',
   path: '/' + url.split('.com/')[1]
}; 

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  var str = ""; 

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}); 

req.on('error', function (err) {
     console.log('Error message: ' + err);
});     

req.end();
```

I also update your code to a better version and clarify version.

Comment: what did you even change besides the mistake res.ond

Comment: check the stackoverflow question I referenced, I really don't think this solution is going to work

Comment: you must always call req.end() to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer he *did* call ``req.end()`` in his post with ``http.request(opt, callback).end();``...

Comment: so, what is missing is listen to errors, like you sad @PatrickRoberts

Comment: i was assuming that he just didn't put the require code in the question

Comment: there is no difference between "" and '', in fact.. in the official documentation -> http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback they are using ''  :).

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but clean code is consistent, so pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the request npm module for http requests. You get a standard callback.

```
var request = require('request');
opts = {
    url : 'https://www.google.com/pretend/this/exists.xml'
};
request.get(opts, function (error, response, body) {
    //Handle error, and body
});

request.post, request.put, request.head etc.
```

This allows for a fairly standard handling of errors.

Comment: updated to a 'get'. I can't infer that it's a simple application from the question. the request module takes all the guesswork from working with chunked data and only does a callback on('end').