# How to redirect a user based on a returned HTML form response?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form that submits a `POST` request to a Nelify serverless function. The serverless function does some processing and then returns a URL.

I'm using a HTML form to call the Nelify serverless function because using a JavaScript `fetch` was throwing a CORS error. The HTML form does not.

The HTML of the form looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://www.example.com/.netlify/functions/stripe-create-checkout-session" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="priceId" value="price_1JZS_EXAMPLE" />
      <button id="stripe-btn" type="submit">Checkout Test Starter Plan</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of the HTML form (just the button is visible):

[image]

When a response is received the page is changed in place, and the HTML of the form changes to look like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <pre>{"url":"https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_test_a1XZXYz2N8iS46oPtgZUsCFqe434u1c76D5MQrGkNeIW0yjEHbs0oYAx3h#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0T18xUTxGNGFBQjNSZEhXcX0xQH9QcExWRGxwNVRoT39gfDA0f1d3UUM3f0ByQT12Z0IyfXBKbTVVb05jUnFnNlxqf3Y9bl9XMUJWPWlqanR3RD0wVVRUNTU0UH13TDBHRCcpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl"}
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is a screenshot of how that looks on the page:

[image]

With all that said, I have two questions:

1. How do I grab the `url` in the reponse and redirect the user to that page? I know this requires JavaScipt but I'm not sure what that should be.
2. I do not want the response to be rendered on the page. How do I stop it from showing to the user? Perhaps the redirect will hide this?

Comment: BTW Your URL endpoint doesn't exist anymore https://www.example.com/.netlify/functions/stripe-create-checkout-session

Comment: @DVN-Anakin It is an example URL. Not the real one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just grab the URL then follow the tutorial on w3schools here

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp

and if you want to redirect after grabbing the URL then here is the tutorial.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

and if we want url in response see this.

[Get response of url in nodejs (express/http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225458/get-response-of-url-in-nodejs-express-http)

Comment: The url is returned to the form. It is not the document URL. So I don't think something like `window.location.href = document.URL;` as you are suggesting would work. There is also the problem of how to trigger that redirect. I need to wait for the form response and then redirect. Your last link for node.js is also not required because I have already setup nodejs to return the URL to the form, as shown in the screenshot. But would still love to hear any other ideas you have!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TinyTiger okay I understood your problem and my approach would be to use express js and if you are comfortable with express please reply I will edit my answer. And also your response to form is a promise, isn't it?